# local resource (class) is not available in my xaml file

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have a class that extends GridView. I want to use it in my xaml file. It has namespace `MyApplication` so I put in xaml

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyApplication"
```

thank I want to use

```
<local:VariableGridView Grid.Column="1" x:Name="listView">
```

It works but I got error on it

```
Error   6   The name "VariableGridView" does not exist in the namespace "using:MyApplication".
```

I don't get why I get this. I've rebuilt project several times but still I get this.

// edit

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SignDictionary.Model;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace MyApplication
{
public class VariableGridView : GridView
```

Comment: Can you show us the class declaration of VariableGridView just through the namespace up to the class name?

Comment: @Josh I've added more code as you wished

Comment: And both the xaml and class file exist in the same project?

Comment: @Josh yes they exist in same project,same namespace,same directory

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your using statement to:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication"
```

That's where it appears that this control lives.